# Combining HTML and XML from one schema all nested within an element of yet another schema

Tags: xsd

I have been working on learning XML Schema for the past few years now, off and on. I have a pretty good handle on the basics but one thing still eludes me:

I want to be able to create an XML document similar to the following:

```
  <itemList xmlns="http://mydomain.com/namespaceA">
     <item>
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
              xmlns:nsB="http://mydomain.com/namespaceB">
           <body>
              <p>Any HTML code here but I want to be able to mark up
              <nsB:myBTag><strong>some</strong> of the text</nsB:myBTag>
              with tags from namespaceB even if those tags are nested within
              standard HTML tags and even if there are then more HTML tags 
              nested within my namespaceB tags.</p>
           </body>
        </html>
     </item>
  </itemList>
```

Note that inside the `<html>` element the xhtml namespace is the default namespace. This is because I want document authors to be able to use a standard HTML editor and then simply insert the special namespaceB tags where they need them. There will be far more XHTML tags than namespaceB tags in any one instance document.

So, from what I have tentatively learned so far, I think my two schemas will need to look something like this:

#### namespaceA

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:nsA="http://mydomain.com/namespaceA"
             targetNamespace="http://mydomain.com/namespaceA">
      <xs:element name="itemList">
          <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
                      <xs:complexType>
                          <xs:any namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                                  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"
                                  processContents="strict">
                      </xs:complexType>
                  </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
```

(I think the only namespace I need to declare for the content model within the `<item>` tag is the XHTML namespace because then the `<html>` tag in the instance document declares the namespaceB namespace, but I am in no way positive.)

#### namespaceB

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:nsB="http://mydomain.com/namespaceB"
             targetNamespace="http://mydomain.com/namespaceB">
      <xs:element name="myBTag">
          <!--  I am clueless here -->
          <!-- I have no idea how to make sure that additional HTML tags
           can go in here without screwing everything up -->
      </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
```

The big question is: Do I need to do anything to make sure that XHTML and namespaceB tags can be freely intermixed or is that just part and partial of the operation of the `<xs:any>` tag?

Naturally, my schemas and documents will be far more complicated than this. I have simplified them down for easy discussion. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide. If I can get over this one hurdle I can create a really powerful system for educational content that will help educate the whole world for free.

Comment: I came across an example of the use of RDDL in "Definative XML Schema" by Priscilla Walmsley (p. 85) that has an RDDL element within an HTML document and there is more HTML inside the RDDL element. So I will take a look at the schema for RDDL and see how they did it.

Comment: Unfortunately, RDDL achieves its magic by extending a subset of the XHTML standard itself through a very complex DTD with - it seems - more entities declared than used (http://www.rddl.org/#related.resources). Unfortunately, this means if XHTML is revised or when HTML5 comes into full use then the RDDL DTD has to be either modified. Either that or simply accept only a limited - and perhaps aging - subset of XHTML or HTML5 as valid content within the rddl:resource element.

So, this will not work for me. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: In researching RDDL I found the W3C recommendation on XHTML Modularization (http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-modularization/). This apparently provides a means of extending the XHTML schema in whole or part by writing my own module (as described in appendix A). This seems to be one possible _if difficult to implement) solution to "The Big Question," above, of intermixing XHTML and tags from namespaceB.

Comment: An additional - and much easier to implement in schema - solution can be found in the W3C Recommendation for XHTML itself (http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/) in sections 3.1.2 and 3.2. Essentially, "user agents" (the program processing the XHTML document, i.e. web browsers or my educational content display system) are simply required to allow the intermixing to occur without complaining. A standard web browser can ignore my extra tags but MUST process the XHTML tags inside. Therefore, JavaScript, a browser plug-in or my custom application could process my tags as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [XS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#Wildcard), the `<xs:any>` element can have a `namespace` attribute which can have the value [`##any`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#element-any) - this means that the corresponding element in the document can have any namespace.

The `namespace` attribute being absent has the same effect - so you can just omit it.  i.e. the answer to the "big question" is:

- Do I need to do anything to make sure that XHTML and namespaceB tags can be freely intermixed? *No, you don't*
- Or is that just part and partial of the operation of the  tag? *Yes, it is*

*Disclaimer*: I haven't tested this, only read the spec above. If I were you, I'd try validating some example XML documents with your simplified XSDs above, using a popular XSD validator, to determine under what conditions it validates.

Comment: Thanks, 13ren. Unfortunately, the `<any namespace="##any">` will then allow any and all tags in the known and unknown universe. It is very important that instance documents only have XHTML content within the content model of the element being declared.

Comment: OK, actually, any and all global, named tags in any schema document in the known and unknown universe. But you get the point.